# Quickly switch default Apache port

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have default `Listen 80` in httpd.conf. Sometimes I need my own webapp to run on that port so I run it with `sudo`. So, first I need to change Apache port to something else. What I am looking for is a quick one click action to switch in forth and back.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
In order to change the port(s) or address(es) the web server is listening on you must change the web server configuration and restart the web server.

---

I think your best options are:

- Using [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to pass your app through Apache
  Have your app listen on some other port and configure mod_proxy appropriately
- Have both Apache and your app listen on different ports and use a third application to listen on port 80 and forward the requests to the appropriate service.
  Basically writing your own socket-bouncing proxy.

Writing that socket-bouncing proxy (or configuration of mod_proxy) is left as an exercise for the reader - mainly because I don't know your internal requirements.